# multiple string contains comparison

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML.

```
<para>28A.45</para>
<para>28R.45</para>
```

and the below XSLT is what i've tried

```
   <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([\w]+)\.([\w]+)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:variable name="translated" select="fn:translate(regex-group(1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')"/>
        <xsl:if test="number($translated) &gt; 27 and number($translated)  &lt;  40">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains('A | B | C | D', regex-group(1))">
              <xsl:text>PT_05</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains('E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R', regex-group(1))">
              <xsl:text>PT_06</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:text>PT_04</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

As per the above conditions the first `para` should print `PT_05` and 2nd `para` should print `PT_06`But the output that is get is `PT_04` for both (the otherwise condition).

Comment: With `28A` as the first group I don't see why you expect your tests to be true, it looks as if you want to compare `<xsl:when test="some $s in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') satisfies contains(regex-group(1), $s)">`. Or you need to remove the digits from the group to make sure your contains looking for letters works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my answer

```
 <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([\w]+)\.([\w]+)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:variable name="translated" select="fn:translate(regex-group(1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')"/>
        <xsl:if test="number($translated) &gt; 27 and number($translated)  &lt;  40">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(regex-group(1), 'A')  or contains(regex-group(1), 'B') or contains(regex-group(1), 'C') or contains(regex-group(1), 'D')">
              <xsl:text>PT_05</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(regex-group(1),'E') or contains(regex-group(1),'F') or contains(regex-group(1),'G') or 
            contains(regex-group(1),'H') or contains(regex-group(1),'I') or contains(regex-group(1),'J') or contains(regex-group(1),'K') or 
            contains(regex-group(1),'L') or contains(regex-group(1),'M') or contains(regex-group(1),'N')
            or contains(regex-group(1),'O') or contains(regex-group(1),'P') or
            contains(regex-group(1),'Q') or contains(regex-group(1),'R')">
              <xsl:text>PT_06</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:text>PT_04</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

and this worked perfectly.